# cannot display images from api response flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
"poster_path": "/9gk7adHYeDvHkCSEqAvQNLV5Uge.jpg"
```

what should I use to display images like this?
I tried to use image network widget but it didn't work

Comment: does the files at your local? u could add your folders in your pubspec.yaml and load from it. As if the file is not store locally, obviously it needs a valid URL for the image.

Comment: If that response is coming from your server, you need to add the baseUrl, like say your server is at `localhost:3000`, so your image will be available at `localhost:3000/9gk7adHYeDvHkCSEqAvQNLV5Uge.jpg`.Then network image should be able to load it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing the image locally, you have to go to the `pubspec.yaml` file and change the dependencies for the assets. if you want to load it from a url in the internet, you can use `Image.network(url)` .